# Retrieve GPS location using android

Tags: android, gps

I'm trying to get gps location of the current location using simple android program. I used `onLocationChanged()` method for this. But it returning the coordinates as 0.0. The users permission part is correct. This is the code of main one.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GPSTracker gps;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

            double lat = gps.latitude;

            String mlat = String.valueOf(lat);

            tv.setText(mlat);
        }
    });
}



 }
```

this is the gps location class that im using...

```
 public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener{

private final Context mContext;
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location;
double latitude;
double longtitude;

protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context){

    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();

}

public Location getLocation(){


        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        return null;
}

protected void onStart() {

}

protected void onPause(){

    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longtitude = location.getLongitude();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: I used this on a real device not emulator.. but no change......

Comment: Where is LocationListener in your code ?

Comment: Class it self is a location listner..............

Comment: It may take a while before the LocationManager returns a location. You need some way for GPSTracker to let your MainActivity know when this happens, then update your UI.